# Button action in custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I didn't find any normal solution, how to detect click on button or other actions in `UIViewController` that have `@IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!` with custom cell.

My cell:

```
class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, FloatRatingViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var floatRatingView: FloatRatingView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code 
        self.floatRatingView.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: FloatRatingViewDelegate

    func floatRatingView(ratingView: FloatRatingView, didUpdate rating: Float) {


    }
}
```

How to access in `floatRatingView` method to variables from my view ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways this can be done.

The first is using interface builder and there is a guide here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingAction.html

The other option is to do this programatically

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code 
    self.floatRatingView.delegate = self

    myButton.addTarget(self, action: "myButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

func myButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    floatRatingView(someView, didUpdate: someRating)
}

func floatRatingView(ratingView: FloatRatingView, didUpdate rating: Float) {

}
```

Comment: Just depends on your project and use. If you're creating the button programatically, or want to change what function your button calls use the second method. If you have most of your layout in interface builder/storyboards then use the first method.